# Error ssl reason: write EPROTO and wrong version number

Tags: lightning-web-components, ssl, force-org-create, headless-lwc, sslexception

When i try to implement the lwc Ebike project i have this error and I can't understand :

[image]

Comment: Can you include the result of `sfdx version --verbose` and `openssl version -a` . Also, is this specific to your machine ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your sfdx version.  This is a known issue w/ version 55.4.0 and above.

https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/4261

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.